# check if user has credit cards in google pay - stripe android

Tags: android, stripe-payments, google-pay

I am using stripe payment processing with google pay. Google pay has a method called `isReadyToPay()` but it returns true even user has not credit card attached to google pay. Is it possible to check if user has card or not in google pay?

Comment: Is this in `TEST` mode or `PRODUCTION` mode?

Comment: I tried with both if you don't have card google still returns true

Comment: Have you found any solution to this?